# Implementations of spatial indexes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, spatial-index

Are there any good implementations of spatial indexes in Haskell such as R-tree, kd-tree, etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only implementations I'm aware of are [the `spacepart` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spacepart), which seems to be incomplete and abandoned, and [the `KdTree` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/KdTree), which as you might guess has no ambitions beyond providing a kd-tree type.

This is something that's been on my TODO list for a while, since there have been several occasions where I wanted a spatial index data structure, but didn't want one badly enough to stop everything and write a decent implementation on the spot.

Comment: The gloss package has quadtrees too -- no idea about their quality: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.1.0.0

Comment: @sclv: Cool, didn't know that. Wouldn't necessarily want to depend on gloss just for a quadtree, but perhaps the author could be persuaded to extract it as a separate package.

Comment: It's Ben Lippmeier, so I assume A) that he knows what he's doing w.r.t. performance, whether or not he's really worked on it and B) he'd be very open to pulling it out as a package.

Answer (score 3):

The Glome Raytracer uses a bounding interval hierarchy.

It well modularized too, so you'll probably want to start with [GlomeTrace](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GlomeTrace-0.1.2) and [GlomeVec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GlomeVec-0.1.2).

I'm doing collision testing via point/volume queries and ray intersections. It seems to perform very well.

Comment: I should point out that I've had trouble using some of the features in the Glome API... Inside/Outside tests don't work quite as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

there is a [RTree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-r-tree) package on Hackage. It is tested, but it's not as sophisticated as the containers package.